# Enabled directory browsing but getting iis welcome screen

Tags: iis, iis-8

I am hosting some sites on my local machine using IIS 8. I've dropped the folders into my wwwroot folder, and I can get to them by entering the machine name, folder, and index.html in my browser. However, I haven't been able to get the directory listing to show when I enter in my machine name alone. I am getting the IIS Welcome screen.

I went in on the IIS Manager and enabled directory browsing at the root level, and restarted the server. I'm still getting the Welcome screen instead of seeing my directory.

Any ideas? Should I just delete the iisStart.html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either delete the iisStart.htm file or you can remove it from the list of default documents on your site.  Either one should allow you to browse your document root.

- Open IIS Manager
- Click on your site
- Open Default Document
- Click iisstart.htm
- Click Remove in the Actions pane